# Is there a way to enable qss stylesheets parts per OS?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Is there a way to enable/disable parts of a qss stylesheet per OS (platform). So that I can enable one font for MacOS, another for Windows.

I could set dynamic properties for a particular widget

```
this->setProperty("qsysKernelType", QSysInfo::kernelType());
this->setProperty("qsysCurrentCpuArchitecture", QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture());
this->setProperty("qsysBuildCpuArchitecture", QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture());
this->setProperty("qsysProductType", QSysInfo::productType());
```

but that only works with one widget, not the whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard simple way for this.

But you always can hold your CSS resources for different platforms in different files, and use ifdefs, to load it, like:

```
this->setStyleSheet(QFile(
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
":/style/win.css"
#else // add more, if you need
":/style/mac.css"
#endif
).readAll());
```

Or simply use two hardcoded strings with ifdefs.

Comment: I am wondering if I can/could use the precompiler directly with my `.qss` files.

Comment: I depends what you mean. I guess by .qss file you mean like ":/style/win.css" as in my example? Simple answer - no. You can put ifdefs only into c/c++ code (header/sources). Alternative, you can create several resource files, and include only one of them in your .pro file, depending on platform.

Comment: And, if what you want - only change a part of .qss file, consider split your .qss file into several ones. Part that is common for all platforms, and part that is different. And then merge parts in you cpp. I had similar need - didn't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we are now using a combintion of Youw's answer and the approach mentioned in the question.

For conditional `qss` checks we set the properties for a particular widget or widget tree.

```
void CStyleSheetUtility::setQSysInfoProperties(QWidget *widget, bool withChildWidgets)
{
    Q_ASSERT_X(widget, Q_FUNC_INFO, "Missing widget");
    if (!widget->property("qsysKernelType").isValid())
    {
        widget->setProperty("qsysKernelType", QSysInfo::kernelType());
        widget->setProperty("qsysCurrentCpuArchitecture", QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture());
        widget->setProperty("qsysBuildCpuArchitecture", QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture());
        widget->setProperty("qsysProductType", QSysInfo::productType());
    }

    if (withChildWidgets)
    {
        for (QWidget *w : widget->findChildren<QWidget *>(QString(), Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly))
        {
            CStyleSheetUtility::setQSysInfoProperties(w, true);
        }
    }
}
```